# In Lords of Waterdeep, how is Accelerated Plans played?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

In Lords of Waterdeep the intrigue card Accelerate Plans says:

> Choose one of your agents assigned to Waterdeep Harbor. Return it to your pool, then immediately assign two agents.

Our resident "expert" says that this requires you to have one agent already in Waterdeep harbor before you can place an agent and play this card. Is this correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that is incorrect. On your turn, you first place an agent in Waterdeep Harbor, and then, as a result of doing so, you get to play an Intrigue card. So by the time you play that card, you automatically have at least 1 agent in the Harbor (the one you just played).

Now it is possible to play an Intrigue card in other ways, such as a reward for completing a quest. In this case, it's possible that you wouldn't have an agent in the Harbor.

See discussion on this same question here: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/781681/question-about-accelerate-plans-intrigue-card

Comment: I'd say "necessarily" is a more appropriate adverb than "automatically". But who cares =)